# Snapshot transaction Isolation levels: it really works as advertised?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Have you any problems using it on high concurrency environment? It's really works as advertised by MS? I'm using SQL Server 2005 and would like to hear the experiences of those who are/was using it on production.

Snapshot isolation per se is not new for me as I develop/administer Firebird/Interbase as well - where there no explicit locking and all works in row versioning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works as advertised.  Basically the old page is copied to the tempdb database and everyone that needs the old version of the page will be directed to that page in the tempdb database.

If you don't have very fast disks under the tempdb database your system will slow down when snapshot isolation level is used.